# click a href link using selenium on python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to web scrape using selenium in Python. I find all the links on the webpage using

```
elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
```

Below are the attributes of the individual links from the list above.

URL 1:

```
{u'href': u'/video/ca02339f-f8b3-4c34-a34c-5cb317b4618b/fda2decb-2d6c-4d48-9535-7362381688b3', u'_ngcontent-c15': u'', u'class': u'slider-item'}
```

URL 2:

```
{u'href': u'/video/ca02339f-f8b3-4c34-a34c-5cb317b4618b/cdc7f553-e176-49ff-a8a5-d7413dfef534', u'_ngcontent-c15': u'', u'class': u'slider-item'}
```

URL 3:

```
{u'href': u'/video/ca02339f-f8b3-4c34-a34c-5cb317b4618b/710a09a8-6c59-4195-9f1d-991b7807ec94', u'_ngcontent-c15': u'', u'class': u'slider-item'}
```

URL 4:

```
{u'href': u'/video/ca02339f-f8b3-4c34-a34c-5cb317b4618b/9659cf42-35b5-4e48-9a86-3cb2e97ed8bd', u'_ngcontent-c15': u'', u'class': u'slider-item'}
```

I would like to click one of the href link. There are no link texts associated with the links. Is there a way to click just the link without any other information. 
I could not find any information regarding following stand-alone links without any meta info.

Comment: How would you define click the link ? If **There are no link texts associated with the links**, what would you click upon then ?

Comment: Does `self.driver.get(url)` not do what you want?

Comment: Thanks Chris. It did not occur to me at all. It works.